# Display mark above date with no data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bar graph whose columns are a date (`day([date])`, continuous, showing missing values) and with two row pills, the first of which is a table calculation. For the second row pill, I wish to display an aggregate calculation over today's date. I am using

```
if [date] == today()
then { exclude [date] : sum(int([measure] == 1)) }
end
```

This correctly displays the desired sum when today's date is in the data. However, my issue is that when there is no data for today's date, the mark for the second row pill disappears.

Is it possible to always display this calculation over today's date regardless of whether the date appears in the data?

Comment: FYI, I believe show missing values only affects discrete fields

Comment: Does your requriement mean when no data is retrived from database? If yes what would show on sheet excluding mark?